# RedirectToLocal does not work

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a login page that gets called through a View that is using Angular as well.

Once it hits the "RedirecToLocal" command.. i step through and I see it hit my Home Controller and returns the Index view just fine.. but when it comes to my browser actually changing pages to the Index, it just won't change and stays suck on the Login screen.  I don't understand why.  I'm going nuts here

Account Controller

```
[Authorize]
[InitializeSimpleMembership]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginFormModel form, string selectedShow)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(form.userName, form.password))
        {
            ...code here...
        }
        return RedirectToLocal("/");  //HITS HERE SUCCESSFULLY
```

Home Controller

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();  //HITS HERE SUCCESSFULLY
    }
}
```

Edit:

HTML & Angular

```
    <button id="loginBtn" ng-click="login()" ng-class="{ 'disabled': isLoading }" class="btn btn-large btn-primary btn-block">
  <span>{{buttonText}}</span>
  </button>
```

Angular LoginController:

```
AccountFactory.login($rootScope.formData);
```

Account Factory

```
AccountFactory.login = function (formData) {
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Account/Login',
        data: formData
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Ajax via $http, the browser will not accept a redirect issued by the server for security measures.

When using ajax, process a successful return indicating authorization and redirect via the client routing (of your preferred flavor).

```
AccountFactory.login($rootScope.formData).then(function (data) {
    $location.path("/");
});
```

Since `.then()` is considered a success callback, an acceptable pattern would be to return a successful `200` status code from your API for success and a `40x` for an unsuccessful authorization attempt.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginFormModel form, string selectedShow)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(form.userName, form.password))
    {
        ...code here...
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
    }
    else 
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(403);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Also, when you state "process a successful return indicating authorization and redirect via the "client routing" of your prefered flavor".. do you mean I can only redirect using UI-Router or NGRoute?  It won't work on the back end?

Comment: @user1189352 I've added additional clarification.  You can't redirect on the backend.  You have to interpret the result of your authorization attempt and decide on an action on the client.  And yes, as long as you properly set your authentication cookie, setting $location should work for you.  If it doesn't, you can always set $window/window to "/";

Comment: @user1189352 happy to help!